# Why do these 2 UIGraphics drawing operations produce images of different sizes?

Tags: swift, core-graphics

To convert `CGPDFPage` to `UIImage`, I tested these 2 functions:

```
private func convertToImg(page: CGPDFPage) -> UIImage {
    let pageRect = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
    
    let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
    format.scale = 1 // Set scale to 1 to prevent image to be drawn bigger than the original
    
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pageRect.size, format: format)
    let img = renderer.image { ctx in
        UIColor.white.set() // White Background
        ctx.fill(pageRect)
        
        ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageRect.size.height)
        ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

        ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(page)
    }

    DLog("Image has \(String(describing: img.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)?.count)) size")
    return img
}

private func convertToImg2(page: CGPDFPage) -> UIImage {
    let pageRect = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size)
    let context:CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.saveGState()
    UIColor.white.set() // White Background
    context.fill(pageRect)
    context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageRect.size.height)
    context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    context.concatenate(page.getDrawingTransform(.mediaBox, rect: pageRect, rotate: 0, preserveAspectRatio: true))
    context.drawPDFPage(page)
    context.restoreGState()
    let pdfImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    
    if let pdfImage = pdfImage {
        DLog("Image has \(String(describing: pdfImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)?.count)) size")
    }
    
    return pdfImage ?? UIImage()
}
```

**Test procedure:**

- PDF as input, with 1 single-page with resolution = 300 × 2108
- PDF File size: 320kB

**Test results:**

Output function 1 (UIImage):

- resolution = 300 × 2108
- Image size: 607kB

Output function 2 (UIImage):

- resolution = 300 × 2108
- Image size: 344 kB

Why does the first function outputs an image with a bigger file size?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. The trick was to set
`format.preferredRange = .standard`
where `format` is of class `UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat`

It limits the color range used and therefore limits the output file size.